# Fetch data using Ajax on Rails App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm new to ruby on rails so please forgive the question. I am trying to update the number of fans who have liked a post using Ajax. I'm able to use Ajax to show in real time whenever a user has liked a post, but to get the total number of folks who have liked all my posts - I need to refresh my page and wait for that data to pull from my rails controller into <%= @likersnumero %> - I would like to use Ajax so I don't have to refresh my page. I have listed below all my relevant code down below. Thank you so much guys!!

**Index.html.erb**

```
<div class="tabbable-panel">
    <div class="text-center" id="tabbable-line">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills center-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a data-toggle="pill" href="#trending">
                    Fans&nbsp
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <br>
                    <div class="pillnumber" >
                        <%= @likersnumero%> #This is What I want to Update using Ajax
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="trending" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Fans and Friends&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>   

<div class="containerbox like-feed-wrapper">
    <%- @likers.each do |liker| %>
      <%= render "like_feed", liker: liker %>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**_item.html.erb**

```
<div class="row" style="border-top:1px solid #e5e5e5;">
  <div class="col-md-3" id="<%= dom_id(item, :likes_wraper) %>" >
    <%= render partial: "likes", locals: {item: item} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_likes.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.likes?(item) %>
    <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" ></i>'
    .html_safe, item_like_path(item), method: :delete, remote: true %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
    .html_safe, item_like_path(item), method: :post, remote: true %>
<% end %>
<% item.likes.each do |like| %>
    <%= image_tag like.user.avatar, width: 20%>
<% end %>
<span class="likes-count">
    <%= item.likes_count %>
</span>
```

**Create.js.erb**

```
(function () {
$("#likes_wraper_item_<%= @item.id%>")
    .html("<%=j render partial: "items/likes", locals: {item: @item} %>");

var $feedLiker = $(".like-feed-wrapper #feed_liker_user_<%= current_user.id %>");

if ($feedLiker.length !== 0 ) {
    $feedLiker
        .find(".likes-count-val")
        .text("<%= current_user.likes.select { |like| like.item.user == current_user }.count %>");
} else {
    $(".like-feed-wrapper")
        .append("<%=j render partial: "items/like_feed", locals: {liker: current_user} %>")
}
})();
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
(function () {
$("#likes_wraper_item_<%= @item.id%>").html("<%= j render partial: "items/likes", locals: {item: @item} %>");

var $feedLiker = $(".like-feed-wrapper #feed_liker_user_<%= current_user.id %>");


if ($feedLiker.length !== 0 ) {

    $feedLiker
        .find(".likes-count-val")
        .text("<%= current_user.likes.select { |like| like.item.user == current_user }.count %>");
} else {

    $feedLiker.remove();
}
})();
```

**_like_feed.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to liker, id: dom_id(liker, :feed_liker) do%>
    <div class="box">
      <%= image_tag liker.avatar, width: 70, class: "css-style"   %>
      <br>
      <strong><%= liker.username %></strong>
      <span class="pull-right">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp
          <span class="likes-count-val">
            <%= liker.likes.select { |like| like.item.user == current_user }.count %>
          </span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index    
@items = Item.order("created_at DESC")
if current_user.present?
@likersnumero = current_user.items.joins(:likes).map(&:user).count
end
end

def show
end

def new
@item = current_user.items.build
end

def edit
end

def create         
@item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
respond_to do |format|

  if @item.save

    format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
end
```

Comment: So... what have you tried to get it working yourself and what errors are you getting? What have you googled about using AJAX with Rails?

Comment: Taryn - I have looked at three SO questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883546/rails-jquery-ajax-request-not-executing?rq=1. I tried putting remote: true on the parent div="pillnumber" and placing it in my create.js.erb using ``.find(".pillnumber") but that didn't work. I'm wondering if I should be using JSON to make a put request

Comment: The remote-true thing won't magically do anything... but I think the "find pillnumber' stuff is the right direction. Can you tell me what didn't work about it? did you see errors in the javascript console? Are you aware that if you use `class="pillnumber"` instead of `id="pillnumber"` then you need to treat it like an array in the JS (instead of a single element that you can just update the content of)?

Comment: Taryn I didn't know that about the array. Whenever i put .find(".pillnumber") that doesn't anything I think partly because the way my function is set up in create.js.erb  > it requires a modification as it stands now wrapper item first but not the pillnumber

Comment: If there's only one instance of `pillnumber` on the page, then change it to an id (they're easier to work with) and then try something like: `$("#pillnumber").html("<%= @likersnumero %>");` And check the console for bugs (as the above makes lots of assumptions and could be wrong) :)

Comment: Taryn, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it several times. Where do I place that particular code - I'm thinking in create.js.erb. I tried it at the very button after the else statement but the only thing that happens is that my pillnumber that was there before disappears (so instead of showing three it shows blank and before I clicked it was 2). No errors appear appear in my Network XHR section

Comment: Cool yes create and also destroy are both likely to change the pillnumber - so you need to put it in both. Cool... it removes the old one - that's a good start - it means you've got the code working and changing the right spot in the html... now you just need to figure out what to fill in in the JS to make the real number show up... so... what's in your controller that goes and sets `@likersnumero` ?

Comment: can you tell me where is the click action on the view...on which you need to update the count of likes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers were super helpful in guiding me to the eventual solution that worked, but they didn't exactly solve it 100%. In case, anyone else finds themselves in a similar bind. I've provided the solution that worked for me below.

**Create.js.erb**

```
(function () {
  var fansCount;


$("#likes_wraper_item_<%= @item.id%>")
    .html("<%=j render partial: "items/likes", locals: {item: @item} %>");

var $feedLiker = $(".like-feed-wrapper #feed_liker_user_<%= current_user.id %>");

if ($feedLiker.length !== 0 ) { 
    $feedLiker
        .find(".likes-count-val")           
        .text("<%= current_user.likes.select { |like| like.item.user == current_user }.count %>");
} else {
    $(".like-feed-wrapper")
        .append("<%=j render partial: "items/like_feed", locals: {liker: current_user} %>")
}

fansCount = $("#pillnumber").text().trim();
$("#pillnumber").text(Number(fansCount) + 1);
})();
```

**destory.js.erb**

```
(function () {
  var fansCount;


$("#likes_wraper_item_<%= @item.id%>").html("<%= j render partial: "items/likes", locals: {item: @item} %>");

var $feedLiker = $(".like-feed-wrapper #feed_liker_user_<%= current_user.id %>");


if ($feedLiker.length !== 0 ) {
    $feedLiker
        .find(".likes-count-val")
        .text("<%= current_user.likes.select { |like| like.item.user == current_user }.count %>");

    if ($feedLiker.find(".likes-count-val").text().trim() === "0") {
    $feedLiker.remove();
  }
}

fansCount = $("#pillnumber").text().trim();
$("#pillnumber").text(Number(fansCount) - 1);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one instance of `pillnumber` on the page, then change that html to an id (they're easier to work with) eg:

```
<div id="pillnumber" >
  <%= @likersnumero%> #This is What I want to Update using Ajax
</div>
```

and then add the following (or something like it) to your create.js and destroy.js:

```
$("#pillnumber").html("<%= @likersnumero %>");
```

Make sure that you are setting up `@likersnumero` in your controller actions, or there will be no output.

And always check the console for bugs (as the above makes lots of assumptions and could be wrong - I can't actually test this code outside of your full app (and don't want to) - so check and fix bugs) :)

Answer (score 0):

i had implemented similar scenario,where i update entire small container having `thumbs-up,thumbs-down and the overall likes count` rather than just the count.You can use the container with  `id=tabbable-line` and replace it everytime someone click thumbs-up.

for example --

```
####your view showing the `likes` with uniq id

        ###this should be _like.html.erb====================
       <div class="text-center" id="tabbable-line">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills center-tabs">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#trending">
                            Fans&nbsp
                            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <br>
                            <div class="pillnumber" >
                                <%= @likersnumero%> #This will be updated from like.js.erb which will render _like.html.erb contaning this small container.
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
              </div>


    in items controller having `like` action===========
        ##item_like_path
        def like
           @item =  Item.find(params[:id])
           ###your logic to increment the item.likes count and get new @likersnumero
           @likersnumero = add_or_update_likes_count(@item)
           ##once you have latest count,render like.js.erb which will render _like.html.erb to update entire _like.html.erb
        end

    ###like.js.erb================================
    ##if you need to update dynamic container with ids 
    ###var like_id = "<%= j @like.id.to_s%>";
    ###$('#tabbable-line_'+like_id).html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'items/like')) %>");
    ##now render again the container - _like.html.erb  
    $('#tabbable-line').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'items/like')) %>");
```

Hope it helps...